# Run href.replace on all matching elements on screen

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Right now, I'm being forced to run my method on mouseover, which essentially changes part of the URL of matching links to something else. If I just hit all the elements on the entire page, I get a huge performance hit and even crashes. If I use the mouseover action, it doesn't function properly with a 3rd-party Chrome extension that it's intended to work with, but at least is stable.

Here's where I'm at:

```
$('body').on('mouseover', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(this.href.match(/example.com/g)){
      this.href = this.href.replace('example.com', 'newexample.org');
  }
});
```

I'd like to, instead of executing this `.replace` on mouseover, instead take all `example.com` links and convert them when they're on screen, including as you scroll down. That way, it breaks up all the links into slightly more manageable chunks. That's the only way I can think of doing it without hitting all the page links at once and taking the performance hit.

Is it possible?

Comment: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport extends jQuery selectors to add `:in-viewport`

Comment: So, I'd just be adding this as an additional jquery file to my manifest.json, and then it's just a matter of figuring out the syntax?

Comment: Yes, I think so (but I haven't written extensions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the jQuery Viewport extension from http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport

Then you can use a scroll handler that does something like:

```
$('a:in-viewport[href*="example.com"]').each(function() {
    this.href = this.href.replace('example.com', 'newexample.org');
});
```

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: in-viewport` I have no idea how to properly connect the two Jquery plugins other than adding them to the manifest just like the original Jquery.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with that part, I don't know anything about configuring extensions.

Comment: On that note, is there an alternative way of manually doing the exact same thing as :in-viewport, but in the same file?

Comment: The viewport extension is really short. Just copy it into your source file.

Comment: Got it all working - added a scroll listener, and we're set :D